# Uploading Magento to a server

Tags: magento-1.7, url-rewrite, server-setup, upload

I have my Magento's file and folder structure inside a folder. I uploaded that folder to the `www` directory of my server. Now I am able to access my store with the URL `myUrl.com/myMagentoFolder`, where `myUrl.com`is the URL of my domain, and `myMagentoFolder`is the folder that I uploaded to `wwww`.

I need to be able to access my store with the URL `myUrl.com`, without `/myMagentoFolder`. I already created an `.htaccess` file and tried writing different directives but none of them works.

Any ideas on how to solve that? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

add blow lines to your .htaccess in root directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?myMagentoFolder/ http://www.myUrl.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Feel free for any query

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried but again with no results. Now I access myUrl.com and while the URL doesn't change, no content is displayed. May I be missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can either login to the backend and go and change the URL to the new one at

`Configuration -> Web -> Unsecure Base URL and Secure Base URL`.

Otherwise you need to access the database and look under the `core_config_data` table and `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url`.

If you did not migrate the database or create a new one, you first need to make sure the Magento installation have access to it.

Look for the file named `local.xml` found under `/app/etc/`.

Edit the file and change USERNAME and PASSWORD inside the brackets for the database.

```
<default_setup>
    <connection>
        <username><![CDATA[USERNAME]]></username>
        <password><![CDATA[PASSWORD]]></password>
    </connection>
</default_setup>
```

Comment: I already did that. My problem is that I need that the url is only `myUrl.com` without the need of `/myMagentoFolder`. I need my server to look by default inside `myMagentoFolder` and take all the content from there but without adding `myMagentoFolder`.

Comment: Any reason why it can't be in the root folder of your server?

Comment: It's just because I want it to be well organised and structured.

Comment: Does the server run nginx or apache?